# How can I trigger a function from a modal component that does not include the function in Angular 14?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I have been developing an e-commerce app with Angular 14.

I am currently working on a form that *can only be submitted upon accepting the "Terms & conditions" displayed in a modal.

The `FormComponent` and `ModalComponent` are sibling components.

In `form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent {
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      first_name: new FormControl(''),
      last_name: new FormControl(''),
      phone: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  public openDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    // Dialog options
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = '420px';

    this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, dialogConfig);
  }

  public sendFormData() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

In the form componant's template:

```
<h1>Get in touch</h1>

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-grid">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Fast name:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="first_name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Last name:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="last_name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Phone:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="phone" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Email:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="email" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <button (click)="openDialog()" mat-raised-button color="primary">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In `modal.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  accept() {
    console.log('Terms accepted!');
  }

  reject() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

In `modal.component.html` I have:

```
<div mat-dialog-title>
  <h2>Terms & Conditions</h2>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur expedita
    ipsam assumenda sed non aut possimus, dolores ullam voluptates voluptatum
    distinctio aspernatur neque velit eum, eveniet voluptas omnis. Veritatis,
    architecto?
  </p>
  
</div>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="reject()">Reject</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="accept()">Accept</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I have put it all together in **[THIS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-gnjc1w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.html)** Stackblitz.

#### The goal

The goal is to trigger the function `sendFormData()` from the form component from inside the `accept()` function of the modal component?

For achieving this, I did:

```
accept() {
    console.log('Terms accepted!');
    this.FormComponent.sendFormData();
}
```

The above does not work.

###### What is the easiest and most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dialog component, you pass a result to the `close()` function:

```
accept() {
  this.dialogRef.close('ACCEPTED');
}

reject() {
  this.dialogRef.close('REJECTED');
}
```

In your form component's `openDialog()` function, you handle the result:

```
public openDialog() {
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
  dialogConfig.width = '420px';

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, dialogConfig);
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    if (result === 'ACCEPTED') {
      this.sendFormData();
    }
  });
}
```